# uitableviewcelleditingstyledelete customize minus button

Tags: ios, uitableview, objective-c-blocks

Is it possible to align the minus button that appears with the UITableViewCell editing style 'UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete' ? By default the minus button is always aligned horizontally centre to the cell. Is there some way to align it, say, some 10px from the top of the cell ? Help please.